# specific position for each turtle in netlogo

Tags: procedure, netlogo

I have the following code in the setup procedure in netlogo

```
  set-default-shape Mappers "target"
  create-mappers MappersCounterSlider
  [
    set color red
    set size 1.5  ;; easier to see
    set label-color blue - 2
    set xcor 10
    set ycor random 11

  ]
```

I need to change the random 11 to a specific value for each turtle I create, for example if I have 5 turtles I want to have 5 turtles in diffrent 5 fixed positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need specific y coordinates for each turtle I am afraid you are going to have to set them yourself.

If you don't care about which turtle is at which y coordinate, you can have a list of possible y coordinates, which each turtle will then remove from to determine their y-coordinate

For example, if you needed the turtles to start at y coordinates 1, 2, 5, 8 and 9, create a list:

```
let y-coordinates (list 1 2 5 8 9)
```

Then when you create your turtles, set their y coordinate to be a random element removed from the list.

```
let remove-index random length y-coordinates
set ycor item remove-index y-coordinates
set y-coordinates remove-item remove-index y-coordinates
```

That way, if you want to add any more fixed y-coordinates, you can simply add it to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the position during the create process by incrementing a global variable. Like the following:

```
globals [posn]

to setup
  set posn -10
  create-turtles 5
  [
    set color red
    set size 1.5  ;; easier to see
    set label-color blue - 2
    set xcor 10
    set posn posn + 3
    set ycor posn

  ]
end
```